# Regex to find web addresses in short copy

Tags: javascript, regex

Having a short copy I need to match all occurrences of links to websites. To keep things simple a need to find out addresses in this format:

```
www.aaaaaa.bbbbbb
http://aaaaaa.bbbb
https://aa.bbbb
```

but also I need to take care of longer www/http/https versions:

```
www.aaaaa.bbbb.ccc.ddd.eeee
```

etc. So basically number of subdomains is not known. Now I came up with this regex:

```
(www\.([a-zA-Z0-9-_]|\.(?!\s))+)[\s|,|$]|(http(s)?:\/\/(?!\.)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]|\.(?!\s))+)[\s|,|$]
```

If you test on:

```
this is some tex with www.somewIebsite.dfd.jhh.hjh inside of it or maybe http://www.ssss.com or maybe https://evenore.com hahaah blah
```

It works fine with exception of when address is at the very end. `$` seems to work only when there is \n in the end and it fails for:

```
this is some tex with www.somewIebsite.dfd.jhh.hjh
```

I'm guessing fix is simple and I miss something obvious so how would I fix it? BTW I posted regex here if yu want to quickly play around https://regex101.com/r/eL1bI4/3

Comment: you could try `(http(s)?:\/\/)?((www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.([a-zA-Z_\-\.])+))`, I don't know if I understand your question completely

Comment: this is for depperm's comment https://regex101.com/r/eL1bI4/4 it looks like it works.

Comment: hmm it seems to fail for addresses with . at the end e.g. "this is some tex with www.somewIebsite.dfd.jhh.hjh. inside of"

Comment: You're alternation doesn't need the spaces.  You're comparing a one type of web address to another.  Based on your regex, you're saying an URL could be followed by a white space character or a comma.  Here's a simplified version of what I think you were trying to do:
    `((www\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]\.?)+))|(http(s)?\:\/\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.?)+)`

Alternatively you can use the links shared that have many examples.
edit: Hit enter and commented submitted instead of just a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you placed the end anchor `$` inside the character group `[]`

```
[\s|,|$]
```

It is then interpreted literally as a dollar sign, and not as the anchor (the pipe character `|` is also interpreted literally, it's not needed there). The solution is to move the `$` anchor outside:

```
(?:[\s,]|$)
```

However, in this case it makes more sense to use a positive lookahead instead of the noncapturing group (you don't want trailing spaces, or commas):

```
(?=[\s,]|$)
```

In the result you will end up with the following regex pattern:

```
(www\.([a-zA-Z0-9-_]|\.(?!\s))+)(?=[\s,]|$)|(http(s)?:\/\/(?!\.)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]|\.(?!\s))+)(?=[\s,]|$)
```

See [the working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL1bI4/10).

The updated version that handles trailing full stops:

```
(www\.([a-zA-Z0-9-_]|\.(?!\s|\.|$))+)(?=[\s,.]|$)|(http(s)?:\/\/(?!\.)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]|\.(?!\s|\.|$))+)(?=[\s,.]|$)
```

See [the working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL1bI4/11).

Comment: almost there, it only fails if there is dot as the very last character in a string e.g. "this is some tex with www.somewIebsite.dfd.jhh.hjh."

Comment: right, updated the regex to fix issue with my previous comment https://regex101.com/r/eL1bI4/7 seems to work fine. Accepting the answer as you pretty much had it, thanks for your help

Comment: @spirytus You're welcome. I also updated the answer with a new pattern that handles trailing full stops.